# Bash: Running a script that runs another script as a separate process

Tags: bash, background

I have a script that does stuff with an ID as a parameter, I want to make it accept multiple parameters and then duplicate itself so that each copy runs with its own parameter from the list. For instance, I run "script 1 2 3&", and I want to see the result as if I were to run "script 1&", "script 2&", and  "script 3&".

I can launch a script inside a script using

```
MyName="${0##*/}"
bash ./$MyName $id
```

$id is basically the parameter I want to put in this script. I launch multiple of them; however, the scripts I launch from within the script get processed in a raw, one after another, not parallel. I tried adding '$' at the end after $id, did not work.

Is it possible to launch a script from a script so that they run as separate processes in the background as if I were to run multiple scripts with & myself from the terminal?

Comment: Are you looking for bash sub-shell started by `()`, But the script may exit while the sub-shell continues to run in background. 

something like 
`while (( "$#" ));
do
  (while sleep 1; do echo $1; done) &;
  shift;
done;
wait`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what I *think* you want... with some dummy example code for the case of handling a single id.

If no parameters are given, it will give you `Usage:`  output, if more than *one* parameter is given it will invoke itself as a background job, once for each of those parameters, and then wait for those background jobs to be finished.

If only *one* parameter is given, it will execute the workload for you.

A cleaner approach would probably be to do this in two scripts, one that is the launcher that handles the first two situations, and a second script that handles the work load.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage $0 <id1> ..." 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

if [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
    # Fire up the background jobs
    for myid in $*; do
        $0 $myid &
    done
    # Now wait for the background scripts to finish
    wait
    exit 0
fi

id=$1

echo "PID $$ ($id) - Hello world, on $(date)."
sleep 5
```

Example run:

```
$ ./myscript.sh 10 20 30 40 50; date
PID 8558 (10) - Hello world, on Tue Jun 21 22:22:10 PDT 2022.
PID 8559 (20) - Hello world, on Tue Jun 21 22:22:10 PDT 2022.
PID 8560 (30) - Hello world, on Tue Jun 21 22:22:10 PDT 2022.
PID 8561 (40) - Hello world, on Tue Jun 21 22:22:10 PDT 2022.
PID 8563 (50) - Hello world, on Tue Jun 21 22:22:10 PDT 2022.
Tue Jun 21 22:22:15 PDT 2022
```

The `; date` at the end shows that the initial script doesn't return until all child processes are finished.

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted, thank you. Turned out that my account on my server did not provide me with enough rights, so I simply could not see the processes running in the back when launched from the script, and I actually had the right way similar to yours. Hence, reworked my code, checked your answer for confirmation, and implemented everything I wanted to. So nice to get such a fast reply, gives me hope for my further endeavors.